# How to design RESTful search suggestions in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I am working on an api rest application in Rails and I have to implement a search action for products that offers suggestions (using pg_search) when the user enters a word until he clicks Enter. My question is where to place this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to be fanatic over REST URL scheme. Just add additional action to the relevant collection:

```
resources :production
  collection do
    get 'search_suggestions'
  end
end
```

Then define `search_suggestions` method in your `ProductsController`.